# Known - Adjective or Verb?

Tags: word-class

I know that "known" can be used as an adjective or a verb (past participle of know) but I'm not sure what word class it is in the following sentences.

A place known for its beautiful scenery.

She is known for being smart.

Comment: The first is not a complete sentence, it is a noun phrase. "Known" functions as an adjective in both cases.

Comment: I agree with TypelA. Here "known for..." is an answer to the question "what is it/she like?". If Past participle functioned as a verb, it would be part of a verb tense (e.g. have/has known...).

Comment: It's an adjective (or an 'adjectival passive', as it's sometimes called).